# Windows 10 created problems on my app

Tags: android, windows, file, android-studio, compiler-errors

So guys, i updated my SO to the windows 10. And i went to work on my app again, but now there are problems relating the files. There is a build error that i don't know what it is. 
They say :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Cesar\AndroidStudioProjects\Moises\.gradle\2.2.1\taskArtifacts\cashe.properties.lock (Access denied)
```

I went to that directory, and the file named above is there. What's happening guys ? i don't want to rewrite my app again :x

Comment: Try giving AndroidStudio administrator permissions. If it works, maybe you just have to change the permissions to the file.

Comment: You mean like open with admin ?

Comment: yes, it seems like Android Studio have no permissions for this file

Comment: Omg, i'm so stupid. It worked, i don't know why i didn't think of that.
Thanks a lot man !

Comment: I'll post it as answer for future users with the same problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving AndroidStudio administrator permissions (open as admin). If it works, maybe you just have to change the permissions to the file.